# how to upload image as part of a form with other fields in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just trying record student information with an image profile. I want to upload the image as part of the form to `application->Image` directory and save the image name to the database.

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include ="StudentId,StudentName,StudentLastName,StudentPhone,StudentAge,StudentEmail,photo")] Student student , HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + file.FileName);
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

in my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Students", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentAge, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentAge, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentAge, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.photo, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

but when i upload, it generates an error message

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

on this line

> file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + file.FileName

please help me this issue please...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

change it:

From

```
file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + file.FileName
```

To

```
file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but still getting the same error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the same line

Comment: do you have a folder named Images in your project?

Comment: If folder exists then check file.Filename if has a value or null.

Comment: I am confused this is an image actually, where's this image came from?

Comment: this image is coming from the form. i trace the network and the image parameter and its name is also available. but it give such an error.

Comment: I saw this HttpPostedFileBase is just Consider a file only like WORD,EXCEL,PDF,CSV but not an image.

Comment: Edited the answer above and add close parenthesis at the end.

Comment: yes is added the parenthesis.i tested to upload Word file but the same problem still exists.

Comment: what is the content of your file.filename? is it image or not?

Answer (score 0):

`System.NullReferenceException` means that something is `null` at this reported line of code.

In this situation, it should be your `HttpPostedFileBase file`.
Try run the application in debug mode, and check again the name of your upload field, whether it's set as "file". MVC asp.net using Name attribute to define parameter.

In my case, I'm using a simple `<input>` to do the upload file and another `<img>` for displaying:

View:

```
<!--Displaying: You need some code for this-->
<img src="@ViewBag.ImagePath" alt="Message picture" style="width:100%;">

<!--Uploading-->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Students", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <!-- Your other part of form -->

    <!-- Uploading -->
    <input type="file" name="file" />
}
```

Controller:

```
// extract only the filename
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
// initial new path for upload file
var newSPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);
// store file
file.SaveAs(newSPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include ="StudentId,StudentName,StudentLastName,StudentPhone,StudentAge,StudentEmail,photo")] Student student , HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         var fileName=Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
         var path=Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + fileName)
         photo.SaveAs(path);
         db.Students.Add(student);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```